# How to read all files in a directory starting with specific path in PHP

Tags: php, file, glob, file-read

I have filenames like `fm.txt fm_1.txt, fm_2.txt`. When run a script i need to get the count of all the files starting with fm.

```
$files = glob(PATH_DIR.'_*.txt');
echo count($files);
```

shows me `count` of 0.

```
$files = glob(PATH_DIR.'*.txt');
echo count($files);
```

shows me count of 1.

Actually 1 have 3 files suppose `fm.txt, fm_1.txt, fm_2.txt`. I guess the second snippet shows only `fm.txt` count, How to modify that line to get the cont of files with `_` too

Comment: `I guess`. And if you output `$files` you will see the real picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readdir function http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

```
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir(PATH_DIR)) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ( strpos($entry, 'fm') === 0 ){
            ++$count;
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);

}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following structure in the current directory:

```
test.php
test
├── fm_1.txt
├── fm_2.txt
└── fm.txt
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$dir = __DIR__ . '/test';
$files = glob("${dir}/fm{,_[0-9]*}.txt", GLOB_BRACE);
var_dump($files);
```

Then `php test.php` will produce output similar to the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(28) "/home/ruslan/tmp/test/fm.txt"
  [1]=>
  string(30) "/home/ruslan/tmp/test/fm_1.txt"
  [2]=>
  string(30) "/home/ruslan/tmp/test/fm_2.txt"
}
```

---

The glob expressoin `fm{,_[0-9]*}.txt` due to the brace expansion is expanded to the following patterns:

- `fm.txt`
- `fm_[0-9]*.txt`

since there are two items listed within the braces: an empty value and `_[0-9]*`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell glob function that you want files that start with fm so try this:

glob(PATH_TO_YOUR_DIR . "fm*.txt")

Comment: Strange. I have tested this on my local setup and it works fine.

Comment: Here is what I am doing: I have a directory /var/www/wms/public/test/ in which I have 4 files: fm.txt, fm_1.txt, fm_2.txt, fm_3.txt

Comment: $path = "/var/www/wms/public/test/";
$files = glob($path . "fm*.txt");
This gives me correct result. Returns all files with name starts with fm